# Land Use/ Land Cover for Hawaii?

Tags: data, united-states, land-cover

Talking to a friend of mine in Hawaii and I am from New Mexico. My question to you all is to see if there is a land use/land cover dataset for Hawaii?

Comment: Thanks everyone, He is interested in Aglands, forestlands and rangelands. That will help him a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I poked around on the [State of Hawaii GIS](http://www.state.hi.us/dbedt/gis/download.htm) site but most of the layers were too general or too old.

The NOAA Coastal Services Center has some [Landsat ETM derived land-cover data for Hawaii](http://www.csc.noaa.gov/crs/lca/hawaii.html).  There's also some 2.4m [Quickbird-derived land-cover data](http://www.csc.noaa.gov/ccap/pacific/) for all islands except the Big Island.

[image: Oahu land cover]

Hope that helps!

Comment: +1 Good find.  2.4 m land cover is hard to come by.

Answer (score 3):

Slight correction to a previous answer...

NOAA's Coastal Services Center now has 2.4 meter land cover data for all eight of the main islands of Hawaii.  Here is the link to the Coastal Change Analysis Program (CCAP) high-resolution land cover download page:

http://www.csc.noaa.gov/digitalcoast/data/ccaphighres/download.html

Select from the drop down menu on the right.

Answer (score 2):

I came across the [Global Land Cover Facility](http://glcfapp.glcf.umd.edu:8080/esdi/index.jsp) from the University of Maryland while searching for [stereo satellite image sets](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/17822/986).

Answer (score 2):

We've got some NLCD 2001 data from the USGS on WeoGeo.

http://market.weogeo.com/datasets/open_nlcd_2001_hawaii_land_co.html

If you look at all the land cover data we have for Hawaii, you may see something you need:

http://market.weogeo.com/?query=Land%20cover&lat=20.46&lon=-157.505&zoom=7&layers=BT

We've got hundreds of mostly free land cover datasets from around the world.

http://market.weogeo.com/?query=Land%20cover&lat=0&lon=0&zoom=1&layers=BT

Answer (score 2):

Fairly easy to find in the national dataset. I really like the way it works also.
[Glovis](http://glovis.usgs.gov)
[EarthExplorer](http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov)

[image: NLCD Data]